# How to make mongodb regex case insensitive in c# mongodb driver?

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb, case-sensitive

i am trying to make a search feature , but id like to find products by multiple fields, including name except it isnt case insensitive and i have no idea how to do this, thank you.
heres the full function :

```
public async Task<List<Product>> findProduct(string query){
            List<Product> all = new List<Product>();
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var pattern = new BsonRegularExpression(query);
            var emailFilter = builder.Regex("email",pattern);
            var nameFilter = builder.Regex("nom",pattern);
            var matriculeFilter = builder.Regex("matricule",pattern);
            var combinedOr = builder.Or(matriculeFilter | emailFilter | nameFilter);
            var count = await getCollection("produits").Find(combinedOr).CountAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            if(count >= 0 ){
                var result = await getCollection("produits").Find(combinedOr).ToListAsync();
                foreach(var doc in result){
                all.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(doc));
                }
            return all;
            }
            else{
                return all;
            }
        }
```

the part that takes care of the name :

```
var nameFilter = builder.Regex("nom",pattern);
```

sorry if my variable names are fluctuating between french and english. thanks.

Comment: Use [BsonRegularExpression Constructor (String, String)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonRegularExpression__ctor_1.htm) Second parameter is Regular expression options, would be `"i"` for case insensitive.

Comment: oh, that worked nicely, ok im gonna bother you with another issue here a bit, it seems when i search by id, nothing shows up, the id is an integer in my mongodb collection, but regex excepts a string, i dont know if that is the reason i cant find my products or not, thanks for the massive help!

Comment: id corresponds to matricule in  the code by the way.